# Qt 5.6 QLineEdit loses last character when converted into std::string

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlineedit

I uses a `QLineEdit` to get a username and a password as input. However if I convert that input to `std::string` the last character is always gone.

```
std::string s_usr = ui.username->text().toStdString();
std::string s_passwd = ui.password->text().toStdString();
```

this is how I convert it. If I use for example "Test" and check copy the `s_usr` to clipboard I only have "Tes".

Did I miss something or is this a bug?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem you are talking about (using Qt 5.6 with MinGW and MSVC). Please, Try creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you are getting. Something like [this](http://pastebin.com/te8aw9Nk) works as expected for me (no characters lost).